# A graph with only one vertex having an odd degree does not exist

Tags: graph-theory

can I prove this by refering to the [Handshaking lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma)?

Comment: One is certainly odd...

Comment: Yes, use the handshaking lemma.

Comment: @vonbrand you mean a multiple of 2 are certanly odd if the graph has knots that have an odd degree. right?

Comment: Think even+odd = odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A graph having exactly one vertex of odd degree certainly does exist. Consider the graph whose vertices are the positive integers, with two vertices being adjacent if, well, if they are adjacent. The vertex $1$ is adjacent only to the vertex $2$, so it has odd degree. Each other vertex $n$ is adjacent to both $n-1$ and $n+1$, so only $1$ has odd degree. $$1---2---3---4---5---6---7---\cdots$$ What doesn't exist is a *finite* graph having exactly one vertex with odd degree.